# Creating a histogram from sample of normally distributed population

Tags: r

Here is the question: Sample 30 observations from a normally-distributed population having mean 0 and standard deviation of 2. Plot the results in a histogram.

```
sample2 <- data.frame(rnorm(30, mean = 0, sd = 2))
ggplot(sample2, aes(x = sample2)) + 
  geom_histogram()
```

Can't figure out why the above doesn't work. Getting error:

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type
> data.frame. Defaulting to continuous. Error in is.finite(x) : default
> method not implemented for type 'list'

I used this instead, but I don't think it's ideal:

```
sample2 <- rnorm(30, mean = 0, sd = 2)
hist(sample2, col = "blue")
```

Any advice welcome

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `ggplot` first looks for the variable name `sample2` in the dataframe `sample2`, which you didn't specify.

Try to set "pop" (or any other name) as the variable name in the `sample2` dataframe, and map that variable in your ggplot `aes()` call.

Also, use `set.seed(<some integer>)` to make your random draw from the specified normal distribution reproducible. You may want to tune the `bins` argument, to have more or less histogram bins, but setting to more than 10 when having 30 samples is probably too much.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(48235)
sample2 <- data.frame(pop = rnorm(30, mean = 0, sd = 2)) # set variable name here

ggplot(sample2, aes(x = pop)) + # use variable name in aes()
  geom_histogram(bins = 10, fill = "tomato", alpha = 0.6) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your initial code won't work because sample2 is a data frame, which you have correctly input as your data object inside the ggplot2 call,  however, in the aes call you need to input the first column of the sample2 object.

Easiest way to go about this is to name your column when assigning the data frame. We'll call your column col1 for now, but you could name it whatever you like:

```
sample2 <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(30, mean =0, sd = 2)) 

ggplot2(sample2, aes(x = col1))+
    geom_histogram()
```

Alternatively, with your assignment of sample2 you can use:

```
ggplot2(sample2, aes(x = sample2[, 1]))+
    geom_histogram()
```